# How can I restart a network interface?

Tags: networking, ip

How can I restart a network interface? I have a vm that doesn't update its IP address correctly when switching between home and work. The vm runs Ubuntu server and uses a bridged network adapter.

Comment: Under what OS/distribution? How is the network configured in the VM?

Answer (score 6):

Use `ifdown` to turn it off and `ifup` to turn it back on. To restart `eth0`:

```
> ifdown eth0
> ifup eth0
```

You will need root privileges.

[More details](http://www.computerhope.com/unix/ifup.htm) about `ifup` and `ifdown`.

Comment: These commands are not available on a default Arch system, so they seem to be some kind of Debian-ism, or are otherwise deprecated. The link in the answer provides no clarity as to their origin, authors, or even which packages they are expected to be in.

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like you've got that interface configured using DHCP.  If so, you want to kill the existing DHCP client, and restart it.  For a lot of distros, you'd do this:

```
dhcpcd -k eth0
dhcpcd -d eth0
```

but not every distro used `dhcpcd`.  I know some use `dhclient`, and doesn't Debian use `pump`?

Also, "eth0" may not constitute the correct interface name: do `ifconfig -a` to see what that VM has.

Comment: (Not about downvote:) I'm on Debian, dhcpcd and pump are in the repositories. Confusingly, dhclient is not, and that's the tool I got on installation and been using since.

Answer (score 2):

Under Debian, you can tell an interface to get another DHCP lease with

`dhclient -v {interface_name}`

The `-v` means "verbose" and will show you the process in action.

@JustinY's answer will work (`ifup` and `ifdown` commands) if the interfaces are configured to pull addresses from DHCP.  If they are configured as static, they'll just revert to their static IPs.  `dhclient` will attempt to contact a DHCP server no matter what.

Answer (score 0):

the other answers look fine.  Simply wanted to add, from the `man` page:

> ```
>    -a, --all
>           If  given  to  ifup,  affect  all  interfaces  marked auto.  Interfaces are
>           brought up in the order in which they are  defined  in  /etc/network/inter‐
>           faces.   Combined with --allow, acts on all interfaces of a specified class
>           instead.  If given to ifdown, affect all  defined  interfaces.   Interfaces
>           are  brought  down  in  the order in which they are currently listed in the
>           state file. Only interfaces  defined  in  /etc/network/interfaces  will  be
>           brought down.
> ```

generally, the `--all` flag might be extremely helpful to know about because it brings up the network as a whole (provided that the interfaces are marked `auto`).

Comment: the man page of which command? `ifup` ?